# pycharm python selenium scraper apparently not printing correct value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I new to python, selenium, pycharm and such.

I'm trying to print the value of a  on a website ( at the moment of writing this the value is **6320** ).The code is not giving errors but it's printing nothing.

As you can see in the screenshot, when i'm debugging and hovering over the variable, it's displaying **6320**, which is the value i'm looking for.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

# This example requires Selenium WebDriver 3.13 or newer
with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://ici.radio-canada.ca/info/2020/coronavirus-covid-19-pandemie-cas-carte-maladie-symptomes-propagation/")

    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    items = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span[2]').text


    print(items)
    print("hello")
```

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need wait until `.visibility_of_element_located` and use this `xpath`: `//td[contains(., "Total*")]//span[last()]`, although your `xpath` also works, but it is an absolute `xpath` that is vulnerable to change.

```
with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://ici.radio-canada.ca/info/2020/coronavirus-covid-19-pandemie-cas-carte-maladie-symptomes-propagation/")
    items = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//td[contains(., "Total*")]//span[last()]'))).text
    print(items)
    print("hello")
```

Following import :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks! I did not know you could select an item like that with the Xpath ( //span[last()] ) Thank you very much and have a nice day!